# Bootstrap positioning col-xs with div order bound for seo reasons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and I have this situation:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">text</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">photo</div>
  </div>
```

Desktop

```
---------------- ---------
|   text        | photo   |
---------------- ---------
```

Mobile

```
  -------------------------
 |   text                 |
  -------------------------
 |   photo                |
  -------------------------
```

On mobile I need to have photo before text.

```
-------------------------
|   photo               |
-------------------------
|   text                |
-------------------------
```

I tried using pull/push for col-sx but without success.

I know that Bootstrap is "mobile-first" and a solution could be to get them in the order I want on the sx first and then push/pull them in to position on the desktop, but for SEO reasons I need to have text code before photo.

Is it possible ? 
Thank's

Comment: sx was xs: typing mistake, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Approach it the other way around - mobile first...

So put your photo before text, and use push/pull on larger screens.

You cannot use push/pull on xs cols.

BTW, you need `xs` NOT `sx`! :)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-xs-12">photo</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need this could be an approach. I didn't know I cannot use pull/push on xs :(

Comment: The above code i posted would do exactly what you require by the sound of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so this would impact SEO. SEO has nothing to do with div layouts. SEO impacts with headers, images, links, and paragraphs, etc.

However, to solve your layout, you can do like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-12">text</div>
  <!--first push-->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-xs-12">photo</div>
  <!--then pull-->
</div>
```

Comment: `sx` does not exist. it's `xs`. Also, OP wants to change the order on xs screens not sm ones.

Comment: Just thinking of OP! :)

Comment: Seo reason is to have content before. That's why I need text before photo.  (sx is a typing mistake ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You should try [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

If you have just these two items in the `.row` element then it is relatively simple

```css
 /* Of course, use your xs max-width */
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .class-of-this-row {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row class-of-this-row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">photo</div>
</div>
```